# $f(x)=\ln(4x)-2\ln(1-x)+\ln(5)-3\ln(2)=0.$

Tags: calculus

Solve the equation $$f(x)=\ln(4x)-2\ln(1-x)+\ln(5)=3\ln(2).$$

First, I determine the domain $D_f$ of the function $f$. Since the logarithmic discriminants have to be greater than zero, the following inequalities mus be satisfied:

$$4x>0 \quad \text{and} \quad 1-x>0,$$

combined we have that $1>x>0.$ Thus $D_f=(0,1)$. After some algebra I got $$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x_1 & = & \frac{9+\sqrt{65}}{4} \\
    x_2 & = & \frac{9-\sqrt{65}}{4} \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

The only root that falls inside the constraint is $x_1$.

My question is, why isn't the domain $D_f=(0,\infty)?$ Since $2\ln{(1-x)}=\ln[(1-x)^2]$ and $(1-x)^2>0,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}:x\neq0.$

Answer (score 1):

The equality $2\ln a=\ln a^2$ is valid only for $a>0$.

So, the functions $f(x)=\ln(1-x)^2$ and $g(x)=2\ln(1-x)$ have different domains. The domain of $f$ is $(-\infty,1)$ and the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't use the equality $2\ln a=\ln a^2$ to solve this equation because I don't know whether $1-x$ is positive or not? But I already stated that $1-x>0$ since $\ln(\text{negative})=\varnothing$.

Comment: You can use the equality, but you need to check the validity of the solutions you get.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we get $$x>0$$ and $$1>x$$ this gives us $$0<x<1$$ and $$\ln(1-x)^2=2\ln|1-x|$$

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I got.

Comment: and see also my second hint

Comment: I don't see how it applies. And how did you deduce it?

Comment: you will see this in the answer above